# How to handle library specific implicit dependencies in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

./gradlew dependencies shows the following slf4j libraries, should I include both of these libraries or should I use log4j-over-slf4j alone since it includes the slf4j-api

```
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7
+--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.0.7
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7
```

Right now, I include both of the libraries in build.gradle. If I remove slf4j-api, I would run into compile time issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly! You should include both slf4j-api and log4j-over-slf4j libraries in your project. They serve different roles within the SLF4J logging framework.

slf4j-api: Think of this as the "logging interface" you use in your code to make log statements. It's like the language you speak when you want to log something. Without it, you won't be able to write log messages using SLF4J.

log4j-over-slf4j: This library acts like a bridge between SLF4J and the Log4j logging system. It allows you to use Log4j for actual logging while speaking SLF4J. This can be handy if you have other parts of your project that rely on Log4j but you prefer using SLF4J for your application's logging.

Since you mentioned that removing slf4j-api would cause compile-time issues, it means your code relies on SLF4J for logging. So, you should keep both slf4j-api and log4j-over-slf4j in your project dependencies. This way, your code can continue to use the SLF4J API for logging, and the log4j-over-slf4j library will make sure those log calls get directed to Log4j behind the scenes.

In summary, having both slf4j-api and log4j-over-slf4j in your build.gradle is the way to go to ensure your logging works as expected.